# Rails Devise Article from wiki throws error: undefined local variable or method `authenticated_user_root_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I wanted to add an admin and a user section into my rails 6 app, reading this tutorial https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models#

I got the following error when is try to sign in as a user:

```
undefined local variable or method `authenticated_user_root_path' for #<Users::SessionsController:0x000000000824bbe0> Did you mean? authenticate_user!
```

This part can be found in part 6 of the wiki article.

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're just a beginner I would advise you just to add a admin column in the user table/model and not fiddle with the devise setup. It's only authentication, for authorization (permissons) you can use pundit or cancancan.

Comment: Share you routes.rb code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should manually define 'authenticated_user_root' in your routes.rb

```
authenticated :user do
  root 'pages#index', as: :authenticated_user_root
end
```

You can also define another one for admin:

```
authenticated :admin do
  root 'admin_pages#index', as: :authenticated_admin_root
end
```